# Mono on debian error CS0234

Tags: c#, mono

I have a debian server and i saved its mac address on a txt file in the /usr folder.

Every time i start the machine the script i'm trying to do should check the current mac address and compare it to the one saved on the txt file. If they don't match than the machine should shutdown.

The code works on Windows , but i have to make it work on debian. So i installed mono (apt-get install mono-complete) ,created the .cs file containing the code and transferred it on debian machine.

When i run the mcs shutdown.cs (shutdown is the name of the file i created) command i get this error :

> CS0234: The type or namespace name 'NetworkInformation' does not exist i the namespace 'System.Net'. Are you missing an assembly reference?**

How can this be solved?

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          string newmc = Convert.ToString(GetMacAddress()); //current mac address
          string mc = File.ReadAllText(@"/usr/mc.txt"); //mac address saved on a       txt file previously
          if (newmc != mc)   //shutdown if the mac addresses dont match
          {
              System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "-s -t 0"); 
           }
      }
      static string GetMacAddress()
      {
          string macAddresses = "";
          foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
          {
             if (nic.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet) continue;
             if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
             {
                macAddresses += nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
                break;
             }
           }
         return macAddresses;
        }
```

Comment: This script looks as if its written with Windows in mind. You need to do some research on Google, might I suggest you start with researching how to shut a machine down using the command line.

Comment: shutdown now. But i cant include that in the cs file right?

Comment: and yes i agree it was written with win mind because i don't know BASH etc.that's why i was hoping in MONO to help me out.

Comment: K 2 secs, I'm looking into how to do it easily in a Ruby script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface class is in System.dll according to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface . Did you try adding a reference to System.dll when compiling? I believe it's the "-r" argument to mcs.

BTW, what version of Mono are you using. Debian is famous for shipping very old versions of Mono in the "stable" flavour. Mono 2.10.x or higher is recommended, nowadays, as stable.

Comment: i did an apt-get update and upgrade =) version 2.6.7..still no luck =(

Comment: 2.6.7 is ancient, it may not have NetworkInformation namespace, please upgrade to 2.10.x as I said.

Comment: ohhhhh so do i have to update my soures.list file with mono repository?

Answer (score 0):

System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface was introduced .NET 2.0. You need to target .NET 2.0 profile or newer if you want to use it.

If you are compiling using command line compiler use gmcs or dmcs to compile your project.
If you are using MonoDevelop you need to set in project setting appropriate framework version.

Answer (score -1):

This is how you might do this in Ruby.

```
begin
  theMac = File.read("/usr/path/to/text/file.txt")

rescue Exception => e
  puts e.message
  puts e.backtrace.inspect
end

response = `ifconfig eth0`
mac = response.match(/HWaddr (.*?):(.*?):(.*?):(.*?):(.*?):(.*?) /)

if theMac == mac[0] then `sudo shutdown -h now`; end

f = File.open("/usr/path/to/text/file.txt", "w")
f.write(mac[0])
f.close()
```

Comment: he/she did not asked you for the code in ruby... He asked for a typically google answer.

Comment: Thanks David i will try it out immediately thank you so much!

Comment: @cookiesoft Yes I realise this, but from speaking to Aaron here through reply it looked as if he was looking for an easy solution in any language rather than the possible dead end of converting from a script designed to work in a windows environment, to a Linux one.

Comment: Hey david thank you so much..just one questions why theMac==mac and not theMac != mac